# python3: regex need to character to match but dont want in output

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I have a string named

> Set-Cookie: BIGipServerApp_Pool_SSL=839518730.47873.0000; path=/

I am trying to extract `839518730.47873.0000` from it. For exact string I am fine with my regex but If I include any digit before 1st `=` then its all going wrong.

## No Digit

```
>>> m=re.search('[0-9.]+','Set-Cookie: BIGipServerApp_Pool_SSL=839518730.47873.0000; path=/')
>>> m.group()
'839518730.47873.0000'
```

## With Digit

```
>>> m=re.search('[0-9.]+','Set-Cookie: BIGipServerApp_Pool_SSL2=839518730.47873.0000; path=/')
>>> m.group()
'2'
```

Is there any way I can extract `839518730.47873.0000' only but doesnt matter what else lies in the string.

I tried

```
>>> m=re.search('=[0-9.]+','Set-Cookie: BIGipServerApp_Pool_SSL=839518730.47873.0000; path=/')
>>> m.group()
'=839518730.47873.0000'
```

As well but its starting with '=' in the output and I dont want it.

Any ideas.

Thank you.

Comment: `result=re.search(r'=([0-9.]+)',input).group(1)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your substring always comes after the first `=`, you can just use *capture group* with `=([\d.]+)` pattern:

```
import re
result = ""
m = re.search(r'=([0-9.]+)','Set-Cookie: BIGipServerApp_Pool_SSL2=839518730.47873.0000; path=/')
if m:
    result = m.group(1)  # Get Group 1 value only
print(result)
```

See the [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/hwQquE)

The main point is that you match anything you do not need and match and *capture* (with the unescaped round brackets) the part of pattern you need. The value you need is in Group 1.

Comment: You can read more on [*`capturing`* at regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html), BTW. And [this "best regex trick ever" article](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html) is also very educating.

Answer (score 1):

You can use word boundaries:

```
\b[\d.]+
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/hV4iX1/1)

Or to make match more targeted use lookahead for next semi-colon after your matched text:

```
\b[\d.]+(?=\s*;)
```

[RegEx Demo2](https://regex101.com/r/hV4iX1/2)

Update :

```
>>> m.group(0)
'839518730.47873.0000'
>>> m=re.search(r'\b[\d.]+','Set-Cookie: BIGipServerApp_Pool_SSL2=839518730.47873.0000; path=/')
>>> m.group(0)
'839518730.47873.0000'
>>>
```